# Vue.js - Display boolean value of list item in input field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

In short I have an array of data delivered by a backend where value may be strings, numbers or booleans.
These datas ought to be displayed in textfields.
I am using bootstrap-vue's [`<b-input ... />`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input) for the input field.
It works with boolean but the browser announces a warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String, Number, got Boolean with value true.
```

How to solve that, not to see the warning? - I figured that there must be some kind of conversation between the raw data and the filling of the input field.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<b-container>
  <b-row v-for="(value,idx) in this.tags" :key="idx">
    <b-col><b-input v-model="tags[idx].tag" placeholder="key" size="sm" /></b-col>
    <b-col><b-input v-model="tags[idx].value" placeholder="value" size="sm"/></b-col>         
  </b-row>
...
```

Here's the relevant javascripts parts:

```js
...
data() {
    return {
       ...
        tags: [ 
            {tag: 'ONE', value: 12345},
            {tag: 'TWO', value: true},
            {tag: 'THREE', value: 'some text'},
        ]
    };
},
...
```

When it comes to display/render the `tags` `tag='TWO'`, `value=true` the above mentioned warning is issued in the browser's console.
I guess there must be some kind of (back and forward) conversation between data model (tags[x].value) and display in the `b-input`. But I have not idea how to do that and I did not find a good clue in any docs or posts...
Thanks for your help :-)

PS:
in the initial question I mistakenly pasted a wrong browser message:
`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "readonly". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true".`
I did correct the issue in the question.

Comment: You could just convert the Boolean to a string: `{ value: String(true) }`; or if you have a variable: `{ value: myBool.toString() }`. https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/abZgbwz?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you tony19. The data being used will be delivered by a backend. It is the format a backend delivers. I could not change that from the frontend point of view. Nevertheless, you are right that I could do a transformation right after receiving the data before filling my 'tags' property.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML, Boolean props are `true` just by the presence of the attribute, so just do:

```html
<b-input readonly>
```

If you prefer to see `true` in markup, use a data binding:

```html
<b-input :readonly="true">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. I realized that I made a mistake asking the question by pasting the wrong piece of code and that I had to refine it. Sadly, my issue does not deal with the readonly property. It deals with data, especially a boolean value being displayed in a b-input textfield. I corrected my question. I am sorry for my wrong explaining in the first place.